# Error: Kernel is dead, VSCode Jupyter, loop: open files, read

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a simple loop that should open and keep txt files kept in `myfiles`. The `myfiles` list is around 5000+ long.

```
emptylist = []
for i in myfiles:
    with open(i) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        emptylist.append(lines)
```

I'm able to run this for smaller amounts of `mylist` but not for all.

I get the

```
Error: Kernel is dead
Error: Kernel is dead 
at g._sendKernelShellControl (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:1006195)
at g.sendShellMessage (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:1005964)
at g.requestExecute (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:1008506)
at d.requestExecute (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:37:325680)
at w.requestExecute (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:32:18027)
at w.executeCodeCell (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:301076)
at w.execute (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:300703)
at w.start (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:296367)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:311160)
at async t.CellExecutionQueue.start (/home/hjh/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:310700)
```

I tried

```
conda install ipykernel --update-deps
```

but it didn't help.

I even tried `time.sleep(0.1)` but unsuccessful.

Comment: close the file after appending with f.close()

Comment: @darthbaba Same error :(

Answer (score 0):

There's [similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7167#issuecomment-914989856) in github, and the workaround is re-opening `.ipynb` or reverting Jupyter to a previous version, which you can achieve it by `installing another version`. You may have a try.

[image]

Please open a new issue in [vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter) to describe your question and it's kind of you to share issue link here.